# Play template compilation error on initial load

Tags: playframework, playframework-1.x

Since we've been using Play, one issue has continued to plague us.

We have a page consisting of JQuery Ajax calls to a small number of additional Play endpoints.

When Play is first started (seemingly both with and without precompile) it is highly likely that the initial page visit will result in a template compilation exception from any one of the Ajax calls. Subsequent page refreshes work fine, it's always the initial load.

This is affacting both our test deploy (selenium tests intermittently fail) and production enviroment (the fist customer in get's error from parts of the page).

I've included the error below:

```
Template compilation error (In /app/views/CustomerFields/panel.html around line 0)
The template /app/views/CustomerFields/panel.html does not compile : unexpected token:  



   play.exceptions.TemplateCompilationException: unexpected token:  
     at play.templates.GroovyTemplate.compile(GroovyTemplate.java:189)
     at play.templates.GroovyTemplate.internalRender(GroovyTemplate.java:210)
     at play.templates.Template.render(Template.java:26)
     at play.templates.GroovyTemplate.render(GroovyTemplate.java:202)
     at play.mvc.results.RenderTemplate.<init>(RenderTemplate.java:24)
     at play.mvc.Controller.renderTemplate(Controller.java:661)
     at play.mvc.Controller.renderTemplate(Controller.java:641)
     at play.mvc.Controller.render(Controller.java:696)
     at controllers.ClassifiedObjectController.customerFields(ClassifiedObjectController.java:236)
     at controllers.scorecards.ClassifiedScorecards.customerFields(ClassifiedScorecards.java:94)
     at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invokeWithContinuation(ActionInvoker.java:557)
     at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invoke(ActionInvoker.java:508)
     at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invokeControllerMethod(ActionInvoker.java:484)
     at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invokeControllerMethod(ActionInvoker.java:479)
     at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invoke(ActionInvoker.java:161)
     at Invocation.HTTP Request(Play!)
```

There is nothing wrong with the template in question and you never see the error again beyond the first load.

I hope someone can help.

Thanks.

Comment: Is this in PROD or DEV mode?

Comment: PROD mode only. Thanks

Comment: You could try opening the compiled template and see if there are any obvious mistakes there.

Answer (score 0):

We were running into [this issue](https://play.lighthouseapp.com/projects/57987/tickets/1589-concurrency-prpblem-with-groovy-template-compilation) fixed on the 1.3 branch. I patched our 1.2.6 version and the problem seems to have been eliminated.